# Python package function does not match C++ signature

Tags: python, config, boost-python, reuters, thomson-reuters-eikon

I am trying to read a configuration file with the `Pyrfa Python` package. This is my code:

```
import pyrfa

p = pyrfa.Pyrfa
p.createConfigDb("./pyrfa.cfg")  
p.acquireSession("Session1")
p.createOMMConsumer()
```

This code has been copied from https://github.com/devcartel/pyrfa.
When running this code, I get the following error message.

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Pyrfa.createConfigDb(str)
did not match C++ signature:
    createConfigDb(class Pyrfa {lvalue}, class boost::python::api::object)
```

It somehow suspect that this has not so much to do with the `Pyrfa` package. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only missing ()

```
p = pyrfa.Pyrfa()
```